# Does running 2 Monero nodes behind the same LAN help the Monero network?

Tags: monerod, nodes

I've got two machines running seeds/nodes for other projects, and one of them runs a Monero node as well. If I put a Monero node on the other machine, and it's behind the same IP, does it help the Monero network?

Thanks!

Comment: The port forwarding is most likely be the sticky wicket.  Can your router port forward the same port to two different internal IPs?  (would be odd if it did.)

Answer (score 2):

> does it help the Monero network?

Not really. What helps is full nodes and *bandwidth*, if you have >1 node sharing the same pipe so to speak, you are still offering the same bandwidth, just split between daemons. If the goal is to help as much as possible, make sure you allow lots of peers and as much bandwidth as you can share. See options:

```
  --out-peers arg (=-1)                 set max number of out peers
  --in-peers arg (=-1)                  set max number of in peers
  --limit-rate-up arg (=2048)           set limit-rate-up [kB/s]
  --limit-rate-down arg (=8192)         set limit-rate-down [kB/s]
  --limit-rate arg (=-1)                set limit-rate [kB/s]
  --public-node                         Allow other users to use the node as a 
                                        remote (restricted RPC mode, view-only 
                                        commands) and advertise it over P2P
```

And (as per last option above), consider allowing your daemon to be used as a remote node (so make sure you port forward the RPC port also).